# How do I print the month of a specific date without using the function Month() using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, monthcalendar

What I am looking for and couldn't find yet is the code that does what the function "Month()" does (that returns me the month of the date I am using as a parameter).

What I have at the moment is a code where I call the function Date that returns me the actual date that is in the system, and then In another column I call the function month to return me the month of this date.

But what I want to do now, is that instead of using the simple function "Month", to edit that function so it can tell me a month from certain day till certain day (and not simply from the 1st till 31st of each month).

Example: if the date is between the 10th of January and the 10th of February
Return: January (or simply 1)

Comment: So, if the date is on 9.February you need to return January as a month?

Comment: How about `=MONTH(yourdate-9)`

Comment: @Vityata yes excactly

Comment: @Sebastian - the option from FunThomas looks actually quite nice. Remove the offest of days from a given date and ask for the month.

Comment: @FunThomas Wow that simple solution actually worked, thank you!

Comment: @Vityata yes, and this even works for years as well :) thanks for your time!